# Selecting 3 cards with at least one ace

Tags: combinatorics

The question is as follows:

> By drawing $3$ cards from a standard $52$-card deck without replacement, what is the probability that you will have at least one ace?

I understand the answer provided in the textbook, but my problem is more understanding why my original answer is wrong. My thought process was to select one ace from the four, and then add the remaining $3$ cards back to the deck and pick any two.

Thus my answer was $\dfrac{{{4}\choose{1}} \cdot {51\choose{2}}}{52\choose{3}}$

Please could someone explain why this is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Ace Club plus ( Ace Diamond and King Diamond) or Ace Diamond plus (Ace Club and King Diamond) are considered as different in your computation. So you have duplicates.

Comment: What is the probability that none of them is an ace?

Comment: When you have 'at least' or 'at most' in the question, always consider to compute the opposite,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one ace means one and more :

Since there are four aces,

First solution:

for one ace : $\binom{4}{1}\times \binom{48}{2}$

for two aces : $\binom{4}{2}\times \binom{48}{1}$

for three aces : $\binom{4}{3}$

$$\text{P(at least one ace)}=\frac{\binom{4}{1}\times \binom{48}{2} + \binom{4}{2}\times \binom{48}{1} + \binom{4}{3}}{\binom{52}{3}}$$

Second solution:

for none of them is ace : $\binom{48}{3}$
$$\text{P(at least one ace)}=1-\frac{\binom{48}{3}}{\binom{52}{3}}$$

Edit

Comment: Thanks! Really clear and helpful

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that you are overcounting by your approach.
Suppose you first drew the ace of spades, and then drew $2$ cards from $51$ which had the other three aces
and you drew the ace of hearts along with some other card

You would count separately first draw ace of hearts and second draw including ace of spades, and so on.

The long way to compute the answer is to sum up $3$ cases with {one ace, two non-aces,} {two aces, one non-ace,} and {three aces}

But it can be greatly simplified by using the complement, viz

$ 1 - \dfrac{\binom{48}3}{\binom{52}3}$